# Can I restrict a user with Role 'A' to view cases only with the status (picklist) values : new and open

Tags: security, data, user-management, record-access-level, restriction

Case object : private owd

Role :A

User with Role A should only be able to see the cases with status picklist values: new and open.

How can I do this? Is it even possible to restrict users access on Salesforce?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE community!!!. Please Edit your question and add what you have tried so far for this. As currently writes, It's can be done via `Validation Rules`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Restriction Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_restriction_rule.htm&type=5) to control access to specific records from specific people by setting up criteria that match those records. Please refer to the online documentation for more information.